# Protobuf attributes with a hierarchy of generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, protobuf-net

I have a class hierarchy that looks like this.  These classes contain a lot of other details which I have excluded.  This is a simplification to focus on the serialization aspect of these classes.

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Query<bool>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Query<string>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Query<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(Query<decimal>))]
[ProtoInclude(5, typeof(Query<DataSet>))]
abstract class Query
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(SpecialQuery)]
abstract class Query<T> : Query
{
    public new T Result { get; set; }
}
abstract class SpecialQuery : Query<DataSet>
{
    public new string Result { get; set; }
}
```

I also have about 150 auto-generated descendants of generic Query, with a large variety of generic types. For example:

```
[ProtoContract]
class W : Query<bool>
{
}
[ProtoContract]
class X : Query<string>
{
}
[ProtoContract]
class Y : Query<int>
{
}
[ProtoContract]
class Z : SpecialQuery
{
}
```

I've also autogenerated [ProtoInclude] for all those types.  For example:

```
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(W)]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(X)]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Y)]
[ProtoInclude(4, typeof(Z)]
```

The question is, how do I deploy those 150 ProtoIncludes?  I've tried various combinations that seem logical, but I get various exceptions depending on which attributes are present where.  The types that are actually need serialization in the above example would be W, X, Y, Z, only there's about 150 of them.

Can protobuf-net even deal with something like this, or should I try some other kind of serialization?

Comment: Added second answer to address updated question

Comment: (but leaving the original in case it adds context to another reader in the future)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; with the updated question I understand a bit more. I expect the generics in the middle of the object-model are indeed going to make life... "fun". It doesn't work "out of the box"; I looked to see if there were some simple tweaks I could make to support it, but it started getting ugly pretty quickly. I expect it would be better to simply remove the need for the generic in the middle, if possible - perhaps retaining a generic **interface** (rather than the generic class). Here's some code that *does* work; how this maps to your code... I can't tell 100%. Note you don't have to use the `TypeDescriptor` stuff (etc) - it just seemed that since you are using code-gen this might make some things easier...

(I didn't check the `DataSet` stuff - just the class stuff)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using NUnit.Framework;
using ProtoBuf;

[TestFixture]
public class ComplexGenericTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestX()
    {
        Query query = new X { Result = "abc" };
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(string), query.GetQueryType());
        Query clone = Serializer.DeepClone<Query>(query);
        Assert.IsNotNull(clone);
        Assert.AreNotSame(clone, query);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(query.GetType(), clone);
        Assert.AreEqual(((X)query).Result, ((X)clone).Result);
    }
    [Test]
    public void TestY()
    {
        Query query = new Y { Result = 1234};
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(int), query.GetQueryType());
        Query clone = Serializer.DeepClone<Query>(query);
        Assert.IsNotNull(clone);
        Assert.AreNotSame(clone, query);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(query.GetType(), clone);
        Assert.AreEqual(((Y)query).Result, ((Y)clone).Result);
    }

}
public static class QueryExt {
    public static Type GetQueryType(this IQuery query)
    {
        if (query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("query");
        foreach (Type type in query.GetType().GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType
                && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQuery<>))
            {
                return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No typed query implemented", "query");
    }
}
public interface IQuery
{
    string Result { get; set; }
}
public interface IQuery<T> : IQuery
{
    new T Result { get; set; }
}

[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(W))]
[ProtoInclude(22, typeof(X))]
[ProtoInclude(23, typeof(Y))]
[ProtoInclude(25, typeof(SpecialQuery))]
[ProtoContract]
abstract class Query : IQuery
{
    public string Result
    {
        get { return ResultString; }
        set { ResultString = value; }
    }
    protected abstract string ResultString { get; set; }

    // these are to allow simple ResultString implementations
    // without the codegen having to worry about int.Parse etc
    protected static string FormatQueryString<T>(T value)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))
            .ConvertToInvariantString(value);
    }
    protected static T ParseQueryString<T>(string value)
    {
        return (T) TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T))
            .ConvertFromInvariantString(value);
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(21, typeof(Z))]
abstract class SpecialQuery : Query, IQuery<DataSet>
{

    public new DataSet Result { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    protected override string ResultString
    {
        get {
            if (Result == null) return null;
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                Result.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }
        set {
            if (value == null) { Result = null; return; }
            using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(value))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(sr, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
            }
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
class W : Query, IQuery<bool>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public new bool Result { get; set; }

    protected override string ResultString
    {
        get {return FormatQueryString(Result); }
        set { Result = ParseQueryString<bool>(value); }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class X : Query, IQuery<string>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public new string Result { get; set; }

    protected override string ResultString
    {
        get { return Result ; }
        set { Result = value; }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Y : Query, IQuery<int>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public new int Result { get; set; }

    protected override string ResultString
    {
        get { return FormatQueryString(Result); }
        set { Result = ParseQueryString<int>(value); }
    }
}
[ProtoContract]
class Z : SpecialQuery
{
}
```

Comment: Given that the individual queries are autogenerated, it would certainly be possible to turn Query<T> into an interface.  However, I left out that Query<T> implements other generic interfaces and abstract functions, which would mean having to include an implementation in every single auto-generated descendant of Query.  Quite possible, but not very desirable.

The simplest "quick fix" I can think of for protobuf would be to allow ProtoInclude to see the whole inheritence tree, but that would break existing code.

Comment: So given the problems I've faced with different serializers, I've decided that in this case to just write my own.  Since the stuff being serialized is autogenerated, I'm ditching reflection and just auto-generating code to call custom serialization/deserialization routines.  It's not much of a general purpose solution, but better suited to my unique situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the scenario you want to model; however, `[ProtoInclude]` only looks one level of inheritance away.

If I understand correctly, try the following; note that you would need to know the potential generic types at compile time at the moment:

```
using System;
using ProtoBuf;
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Response))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Query))]
class Packet
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    int ID;
}
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Response<int>))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(Response<decimal>))]
[ProtoInclude(3, typeof(Response<string>))]
class Response : Packet
{
}
[ProtoContract]
class Response<T> : Response
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return typeof(T).Name + ": " + Value;
    }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Packet packet = new Response<int> { Value = 123 };
        Packet clone = Serializer.DeepClone<Packet>(packet);
        Console.WriteLine(clone.ToString()); // should be int/123
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  The Response<T> thing was a bit of a red herring.  The real question was about the ~150 descendants of Query<T>.  I modified my question to hopefully make it clearer what I'm asking.